# preg_match returning complete string

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am trying to get numbers from a string but i keep getting the complete string with numbers and not numbers alone

```
$string = "stuff here with id=485&other=123";
preg_match('(id=\d+)',$string,$match);
```

the above results like id=485 but i just want 485

Any help would be appreciated guys.

Comment: are you trying to parse url?

Answer (score 5):

The parentheses say what to collect. You also need to use a delimiter at either end

```
preg_match('/id\=(\d+)/',$string,$match);
print_r($match);

/* should be
0=>"id=485",
1=>"485"
*/

echo $match[1];
```

Edit: See cryptic's answer, parse_str is most likely faster than preg_match. Most things are.

Comment: I hadn't noticed the missing delimiters, and have updated my answer. It definitely works I tried it.

Comment: [script](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/884b2ae5bbc6a82735ad338b3bd81f2f69152366) is working

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = "stuff here with id=485&other=123";

parse_str(strstr($string, 'id='), $output);

echo $output['id']; // 485
```

Without using a regex.

Comment: this is probably faster than using preg_match